# Problems with while loop1

Tags: c

I have problem with an infinite loop.

My expected output is:

```
Initial value is 9
Next value is 28 
Next value is 14
Next value is 7
Next value is 22
Next value is 11
.
.
.
.
.
.
Final value 1, number of steps 19
```

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int count,num,total;
    printf("Initial value is ");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    total = 0;
    while(total != 1)
    {
        if(num%2==0)
        {
            total = num/2;
        }
        else
        {
            total = num*3+1;
        }
        count++;    
        printf("\nNext value is %d",total);
    }    
    printf("\nFinal value %d",total);
    printf("\nnumber of steps %d",count);
    getch ();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: update `num` by `total`.

Comment: This is code to investigate the [Collatz Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture).  There are a lot of other questions about the Collatz conjecture, and it is a good search term (very few false positives).

Answer (score 0):

You never initialize count. However. It seems likely you want to check whether `total` is even, not `num` (which never changes, and therefore will keep increasing `total` forever if `num` is odd).  You should also share what error you get.

Comment: The original code had an open brace instead of a close brace.  You're right about count being uninitialized.  The error is an infinite loop.  What you've got at the moment is a comment rather than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The only way your loop will end is when `total == 1`, which is only possible when `num == 2`. Input any other number and your loop will never end because only `num == 2` will satisfy the condition `total != 1` to end the loop.

Let's say you enter `num=9`. It will go to the second condition and `total` becomes 28. Remember the value of `num` is still 9 and `total=28`. It again goes inside the loop because `total != 1` and does the same thing once again, i.e. goes to second condition; because `total=28` the value of `num` is still the same. Hence the infinite loop…

Do this:

```
total = num;
```

and inside while, check for `total`, not `num`:

```
if (total % 2 == 0) { … } else { … }
```